# Split string with names and middle initial? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset, however it includes Position #, "Lastname, Firstname M ",,

I am able to split it, however i want the middle initial gone, and the white space gone too, this is what i have:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\HR employees\\EE Listing  as of 5-30-17.xlsx')

df['Last Name'], df['First Name'] = df['NAME'].str.split(',', 1).str
del df['NAME']

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

It splits the firstname and last name, but how can i get rid of the middle initial?

Comment: what's the output of `df['NAME'].str.split(',', 1).str`? (or in fact `df['NAME'].str`)

Comment: Well if the user does not have a middle initial it will split it the wait i want, last name firstname, but some have a middle initial and that will be included after the lastname, firstname middleinitial, so Bloom, Daniel J

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\HR employees\\EE Listing  as of 5-30-17.xlsx')

df['Last Name'], df['First Name'] = df['NAME'].str.split(',').str
df['First Name'] = df['First Name'].apply(lambda s: s[:-2] if s[-2] == ' ' else s)
del df['NAME']    

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

The lambda function checks if the second last character in the first name is a space. This removes the initial (if present) while also handling two-part first names.

Test cases: (NAME ---> Last Name ---> First Name)

- Smith, John R ---> Smith ---> John
- JOHN, DOE ---> JOHN ---> DOE
- Jackson, Jean Paul M ---> Jackson ---> Jean Paul
- Gonzales, El Torado ---> Gonzales ---> El Torado

Comment: This fails on "JOHN, DOE" with no middle initial (which is stated to be possible in the comments)

Comment: i have 1500 rows of filled user/names how do i do that? i can't do the full_name method unless its referencing a csv...

Comment: better is probably `lastname, firstname_mi = full_name.split(",", 1); firstname = firstname_mi.split()[0]`

Comment: the csv has 1 column, lastname, first name, the output is two columns, which would be 'Smith', 'John R'

Answer (score 2):

What about a loop to copy the first name up until the space between the middle letter?

```
df['First Name'] = 'dave M'
name = ''
for ch in df['First Name']:
     if ch != ' ':
          name += ch
     else: break
df['First Name'] = name


# OR ALTERNATIVLY 
df['First Name'] = df['First Name'].split()[0]
```

Comment: This is very unpythonic. I would avoid methods like this. Plus, what if the person's first name contains a space? (Anecdotally, my sister has a two-word first name and no middle name)

Comment: I agree with you. The edit is a neater way to do it in one go, but still doesn't account for the two word first names if they are not hyphenated.

Comment: You could do `... = ' '.join(df['First Name'].split()[:-1])` but I'm not sure how that works with a dataframe.